# Finding the remainder of a polynomial P when divided by $x^2 -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help please to answer this problem:

> The remainder of a polynomial P (in one variable $x$) when divided by $x^2 -1$  is a polynomial of degree at most 1, that is, it has the form $ax + b$ for some numbers $a$ and $b$. How can you find $a$ and $b$ if you know the values of P when $x=-1$ and $x=1$?    Hint look at the equality $P = (x^2-1)(quotient) + (ax + b)$ and substitute 1 and -1 for $x$.

Following the hint and using the suggested substitution seems to give $P = a +b$ when x=1 and $P=-a+b$ when x = -1. If this is correct I don't see how this helps  me find and b as requested in the question.

Comment: well, $b=\frac12 [P(1) + P(-1)]$ and $a=\frac12 [P(1) - P(-1)]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the given hint you find

$$a+b=P(1)\quad;\quad -a+b=P(-1)$$
hence solve this system of equations and express $a$ and $b$ with $P(1)$ and $P(-1)$.

Comment: As simple as that! Nice...